# How do I restore corrupted, overwritten Java source code when my IDE only has corrupted file history?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm currently using NetBeans IDE 8.2 on Windows 10, and had last saved my work 2 weeks ago. On opening my one of my Java source code today, I saw that it was corrupted with '\u0000 ' characters, same for the .class file. NetBeans history only showed one version from 2 weeks ago, which was also corrupted. The file has clearly been overwritten, and the Filehistory folder in AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\var\filehistory only showed 4 files with 1KB storage.
Is there any way of recovering my source code, or atleast the .class file?

Other details : The project I'm working on contains 4 other classes, all of which are fine.

Comment: I don't think that there is much chance of fixing this. Take the crisis as chance to learn about version control systems such as git, and the necessity of regular backups for important data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this community is about programming questions, not about fixing broken file system content.

Comment: My advice: rewrite the missing Java class from scratch, and don't waste time on (probably) fruitless efforts to recover it.  It is probably gone for ever.  But even if it isn't, rewriting it will probably be quicker.  (And learn the lesson about the importance of backups.)